# Check status of file during sftp

Tags: c++, sftp

I want to write a C++ code to get a file from server B via server A using password less sftp.The file on server B is infact being copied (via sftp ) from another server C. I was able to retreive the file from server B , however even if the file was still being copied, I was still able to get the file(incomplete file as it was still being transferred to server B from server C). I want to put a check if the file is being copied then i should not get it using sftp and wait till it it is completely moved. As far as i know sftp prompt does not support lot of commands. Can somebody please give me some inputs on how can i achieve this?

Comment: hey thanks for the input DevSolar!!

Answer (score 0):

A traditional way to do this is to transfer the (big) "paydata" file, and a (small / empty) "flag" file after that. You (on the receiving end) wait until the flag file exists. If it does, the transfer of the paydata file has finished; delete the flag file, and do whatever you do with the paydata file.